# Substring based on a word and immediate next third bracket

Tags: class, json, string, parser

I have a large text value as below in a custom field of a custom object.

```
FINDDATA: [XY_8852376.......
{name:"State__SKN", "data": "State__SKN", defaultContent: '', className:"frozencolumnscolor", title:"<filter/>State"}, {name:"Zip__SKN", "data": "Zip__SKN", defaultContent: '', className:"frozencolumnscolor", title:"<filter/>Zip"}, {name:"Specialty__SKN", "data":"Specialty__SKN", className: "text-center", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Specialty"}, {name:"HQ_Call_Plan_Flag__SKN", "data": "HQ_Call_Plan_Flag__SKN", className: "text-center minwidth80", render: checkBoxRender ,defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>HQ Call Plan Flag"}, {name:"HQ_Recommended_Frequency__SKN", "data": "HQ_Recommended_Frequency__SKN", className: "text-center", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Recommended Calls"}, {name:"My_Frequency__SKN", "data": "My_Frequency__SKN", className: "text-center", render: myFrequencyRender, defaultContent: 0, title:"<filter/>Planned Calls"}, {name:"Reason_for_Add_Drop__SKN", "data": "Reason_for_Add_Drop__SKN",visible:false,className: "text-center minwidth100", defaultContent: '', render:reasonaddDropRender,title:"<filter/>Reason for Add/Drop"}, {name:"My_Action__SKN", "data": "My_Action__SKN", render: myActionRender, className: "text-center minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>My Action"}, {name:"Business_Planner_Flag__SKN", "data": "Business_Planner_Flag__SKN", className: "text-center minwidth80", render: bpPlanRender, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Business Planner Flag"}, {name:"Text_Field_01__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_01__SKN", className: "text-center", render: tpPlanRender, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Targeted Product"}, {name:"PDRP_Flag__SKN", "data": "PDRP_Flag__SKN", render: checkBoxRender , visible:false,className: "text-center minwidth80", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>PDRP Flag"}, {name:"Text_Field_09__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_09__SKN", className: "text-center", defaultContent: '', visible:false, title:"<filter/>IC Universe"}, {name:"Text_Field_08__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_08__SKN", className: "minwidth120",defaultContent: '', visible:false, title:"<filter/>Approved for Detailing"}, {name:"Text_Field_10__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_10__SKN", visible:false, className: "minwidth180",defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Recommended Product P1s"}, {name:"Last_Quarter_Calls_By_Rep__SKN", "data":"Last_Quarter_Calls_By_Rep__SKN", visible:false, render: numberRenderer, defaultContent: '', className: "text-center minwidth100", title:"<filter/>Calls Made (Last 3 Mo)"}, {name:"Text_Field_02__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_02__SKN", className: "minwidth100", type:'decile', visible:false, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>ANG Product Decile"}, {name:"Text_Field_03__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_03__SKN", className: "minwidth100", type:'decile', visible:false, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>TTRT Market Decile"}, {name:"Text_Field_04__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_04__SKN", className: "minwidth120", visible:false, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>ANG Motivational Profile"}, {name:"Text_Field_05__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_05__SKN", className: "minwidth100", type:'decile', visible:false, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>SYN Product Decile"}, {name:"Text_Field_06__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_06__SKN", className: "minwidth120", type:'decile', visible:false, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Thyroid Market Decile"}, {name:"Text_Field_07__SKN", "data": "Text_Field_07__SKN", className: "minwidth120", visible:false, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>SYN Motivational Profile"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_02__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_02__SKN", visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>TTRT Rx Volume"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_03__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_03__SKN", render: numberRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>ANG Rx Volume"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_05__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_05__SKN", render: percentRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>ANG Market Share"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_06__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_06__SKN", render: percentRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>ANG Share Growth"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_07__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_07__SKN", render: numberRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Thyroid Rx Volume"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_08__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_08__SKN", render: numberRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth80", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>SYN Rx Volume"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_09__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_09__SKN", render: percentRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth140", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>SYN % TRx Growth (Last 3 Mo)"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_10__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_10__SKN", render: percentRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>SYN Market Share"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_11__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_11__SKN", render: percentRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>SYN Share Growth"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_12__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_12__SKN", render: percentRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>ANG Favorability"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_13__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_13__SKN", render: numberRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth180", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Other TTRT Volume in Favorable Plans"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_14__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_14__SKN", render: numberRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Favorability Gap"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_15__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_15__SKN", render: numberRenderer, visible:false, className: "minwidth100", defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Caremark TTRT TRx"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_16__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_16__SKN", render: numberRenderer, visible:false, className: "NoExport minwidth100", defaultContent: '',display: "hide", title:"<filter/>Silverscript TTRT TRx"}, {name:"Decimal_Field_17__SKN",data:"Decimal_Field_17__SKN", render: percentRenderer, visible:false, className: "NoExport text-center minwidth100", defaultContent: '', display: "hide", title:"<filter/>AndroGel Call %"}, { name: "Bus_Plan_Record_Id__c", "data": "Bus_Plan_Record_Id__c",visible:false, defaultContent: '', title:"<filter/>Source"}, {name:"ttrtdecilecalc", className: "NoExport", "data": function (row){ row.ttrtdecilecalc = row.Text_Field_08__SKN == 'SYN'? 'Synthroid Only' : row.Text_Field_03__SKN; return row.ttrtdecilecalc; }, visible:false, defaultContent: ''}, {name:"androdecilecalc", className: "NoExport", "data": function (row){ row.androdecilecalc= row.Text_Field_08__SKN == 'SYN'? 'Synthroid Only' : row.Text_Field_02__SKN; return row.androdecilecalc; }, visible:false, defaultContent: ''}, {name:"andromotprofcalc", className: "NoExport", "data": function (row){ row.andromotprofcalc= row.Text_Field_08__SKN == 'SYN'? 'Synthroid Only' : row.Text_Field_04__SKN; return row.andromotprofcalc; }, visible:false , defaultContent: ''}, {name:"thyrdeccalc", className: "NoExport", "data": function (row){ row.thyrdeccalc= row.Text_Field_08__SKN == 'ANG'? 'AndroGel Only' : row.Text_Field_06__SKN; return row.thyrdeccalc; }, visible:false , defaultContent: ''}, {name:"syndeccalc", className: "NoExport", "data": function (row){ row.syndeccalc= row.Text_Field_08__SKN == 'ANG'? 'AndroGel Only' : row.Text_Field_05__SKN; return row.syndeccalc; }, visible:false , defaultContent: ''}, {name:"synmotprofcalc", className: "NoExport", "data": function (row){ row.synmotprofcalc= row.Text_Field_08__SKN == 'ANG'? 'AndroGel Only' : row.Text_Field_07__SKN; return row.synmotprofcalc; }, visible:false , defaultContent: ''}, {name:"Text_Field_25__SKN", className: "NoExport", "data":"Text_Field_25__SKN", visible:false, display: "hide", defaultContent: ''}]...........xniojniocsimk....
```

Now I need to extract all those values having '_SKN' as an item of a list.
But whenever I try to put them in a string it throws compile error for double identifiers.
**Error:**

```
 Compile Error: Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier.
```

Can someone please help me with a way out here?
I have to find the text ='FINDDATA' and immediate closing third bracket after that to substring the relevant portion.
I was trying as below. 
String X='....[Above text]';
String JSONString = JSON.serialize(X);

Comment: If that's valid JSON, it looks like you want to *deserialize* it rather than serializing.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON is not valid JSON. Even if your code compiled, deserializing would result in other errors. Please refer to [this website](https://www.json.org/). Long story short, though, is that JSON is a subset of JavaScript, and has stringent rules for how it operates. Notably, `''` is not a valid "empty string." Instead, it *must* be `""`, or optionally, `null`, without any quotes, depending on your intent:

```
{ "validEmptyString": "", "validNullValue": null }
```

Note that field names must *always* be quoted with `"`.

However, let's say you did want to put a literal `'` in your code. To do this, you "escape" them:

```
String aintAintAWord = '"Ain\'t" ain\'t a word.'
```

If you need a backslash, you can escape those, too:

```
String escapedEscape = '\\';
```

Note that, because of that, if you want a literal backslash to appear in your JSON, you end up doubling that yet again:

```
String observeMyBackSlash = '{ "source": "The Amazing \\\\" }';
```

Which results in `"The Amazing \"` (just a single backslash). Note that this is a side effect of JSON escaping literal `\` as `\\`, plus Apex Code doing the same. Each escape has to be escaped again to finally result in a single, valid backslash.

This rule only applies to Apex Code source code. If you're reading your JSON from the database, a Custom Label, an HTTP callout, or another source, that source should *not* double-escape the backslash.

So, for example, if you have a Static Resource with some JSON, it might look like this:

```
{ "Name": "Dwayne \"The Rock\" Johnson" }
```

JSON requires an escape, but since this isn't in Apex Code, we do not double up on the backslashes in this case.